# How the Score is gained For particular Tag after answering?

Tags: discussion, tags, answers, tag-score

On my [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3326275/pratik-joshi), under tags, it shows that I have given 156 answers with a score of 45 for [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery).
I want to know when the score is increased? I gave 156 answers, why is the score only 45?

I basically want to achieve gold medal in jQuery by getting 1K points.  I just want to know how the score is calculated so I can increase it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure it just goes by upvotes/downvotes.

+1 for upvote, -1 for downvote

It doesn't go by actual reputation score gained/lossed like +10 for upvote, and -5 for downvote.

Comment: Hello sir , Is that you think or you sure about it?because its very important to me .I just want that Gold medal in jQuery

Comment: It's not by reputation, it's by answer score.